# Writing values to Razor Pages fields async

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm calling an async Task in my Razor Page. I can set the value of my text box in some places in my code but in others not. My comments show where it works and does not. How can I write a value to my textbox in the place my comments say I want to?

```
<label for="PersonID">PersonID:</label>
<input asp-for="@Model.PersonID" type="text" value="@Model.PersonID" />

public string PersonID { get; set; }

public async void OnGet()
{
    // Do some stuff here
    //Setting PersonID here places the value on my page
        
    await ConnectToPerson();

    //Setting PersonID here DOES NOT place the value on my page
        
}


public async Task ConnectToPerson()
{
    // Do some stuff here
    //Setting PersonID here places the value on my page

    await client.Connect();

    //Setting PersonID here DOES NOT place the value on my page and this is where I want to set it as client will have values returned.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because OnGet and ConnectToPerson return as soon as you hit an async operation. ConnectToPerson returns a Task, which is good, but OnGet does not, so the code calling it has no way to know it had an async operation underway that needed awaiting.

It [looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) you can change OnGet to OnGetAsync to perform async operations, returning a Task.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
        
    await ConnectToPerson();

    //Set PersonID here
        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think technically that answers it though gives me another problem now. The thing I do before await ConnectToPerson(); is create and display a QR Code. The user scans the QR Code and the response form that is what await ConnectToPerson(); is waiting for. But making your change means the QR Code doesn't get displayed now so the thing being waited for can't happen.

Comment: @mjuk: That doesn't sound right. Can you verify that the new OnGetAsync method is being called?

Comment: Yes, have set some break points and everything is executed up to and including await client.Connect(); but nothing after and my page is still loading in the browser so nothing is rendered at that point where it gets stuck.

Comment: Are you _positive_ that you changed the method signature to return a Task instead of `void`?

Comment: Yes, copying and pasting here to be sure - public async Task OnGetAsync() and the code inside does get executed and does call public async Task ConnectToPerson()

Comment: Weird. I can't think of anything else to suggest at this point, except maybe to create a minimal reproducible example and ask a separate SO question about why it's returning before your task is complete.